# Are some combinations of keys behaviors and values behavior not appropriate for a multimap implementation?

Tags: data-structures, guava

Iv'e been looking at the mutable [multimap implementations of Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#implementations-1) and noticed that most of the keys and values implementation combinations are not present.

Java offers 3 `Map` implementations, 2 `List` implementations and 3 `Set` implementations. The `Map` implementation controls the key behavior and the `Set` and `List` implementations control the value behavior. In theory, there can be `3 x (2+3) = 15` combinations. Guava offers 5 of these.

Do the other combination make no sense (they are just worse)? Are they not possible to implement? Are they fine but there is no need for so many combinations?

*(Note that while I refer to Java, this is a question in data structures and not restricted to a specific language. Any language that can manifest hash tables, arrays, linked lists etc. can be used.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`MultimapBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html) to have all those combinations, ex. `TreeMap` -> `ArrayList` can be constructed with:

```
ListMultimap<String, Integer> treeListMultimap =
    MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build();
```

Want `SetMultimap` with `EnumSet` "values"? Use:

```
SetMultimap<Integer, MyEnum> hashEnumMultimap =
    MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().enumSetValues(MyEnum.class).build();
```

(Examples taken from [documentation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html).)

If you want even more possibilities, not restricted to JDK maps / collections implementations, you can always construct own multimaps like using static methods: [`Multimaps.new{List,Set,SortedSet}Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#newListMultimap(java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Supplier)):

```
ListMultimap<String, Integer> myListMultimap = 
    Multimaps.newListMultimap(new HashMap<>(), MyList::new);
```

**EDIT:**

(Direct answers to your questions below.)

> Do the other combination make no sense (they are just worse)?

They make sense, they're just rarer in real world.

> Are they not possible to implement?

They are possible, why not?

> Are they fine but there is no need for so many combinations?

See above - you can construct such multimap using `new*Multimap` or `MultimapBuilder`. They (i.e. Guava team) always take usage statistics across Google internal codebase, so I guess they chose most used ones.

Comment: This is good to know, but it doesn't directly answer any of the questions I asked. Is your answer along the lines of "there is no problem with any combination, they all make sense"? Guava just chose a few... randomly?

Comment: They (i.e. Guava team) always take usage statistics across Google internal codebase, so I guess they chose most used ones. Wait here for them or reach out their [guava-discuss mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/guava-discuss).

Comment: I added _direct_ answers to your questions.

Comment: Thanks, this is good. I'll wait to see if they also want to answer.

Comment: Actually: we didn't think of MultimapBuilder until many years after we added the other types, and now we kind of wish we never had the other types.  If we could go back in time and fix it I don't think we would've had `ArrayListMultimap`, `TreeMultimap`, or `HashMultimap`, though `LHMM` and `LLMM` at least have some features `MultimapBuilder` can't give you.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That explains it even more. I take take it that you approve of the answer :)